# Does Lenovo T400 can only work with up to 4GB RAM?

Tags: memory, lenovo-laptop, memory-limit

Does Lenovo T400 only work with up to 4GB RAM?

On [the detailed specifications for the Lenovo T400](http://support.lenovo.com/en_NO/product-and-parts/detail.page?DocID=PD005598), it says "512 MB, 1 GB, 2GB, or 4GB memory" and "Supports up to 4GB maximum memory". Is it for the total memory, or the size of each RAM chip?

So if there is more than 4GB RAM in the computer, will it do harm to the hardware of the T400? Or will only 4GB will be used, without any other side-effects?

Updated: 
Some people claim that their T400 can use about 8GB RAM under WIndows 7:
[image]
So will that potentially break the laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 4GB are the maximum size of 1 RAM module. You have 2 RAM slots, the Intel GM45 Express chipset supports 8GB, so you can use 2 * 4GB = 8GB RAM.

Comment: Thanks! "1 RAM module" is same thing as a RAM chip? Does LEnovo T400 have the Intel GM45 Express chipset?

Comment: according to this WIKI page it has this chipset: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:T400. There is also a WIKI page about the chipset which shows that it supports 8GB: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Intel_GM45

Comment: by the way, do you know what is the life time of a RAM module in general? (mine current is 2GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1066 MHz)

Comment: RAM has a life expectancy longer than the laptop, in most cases. Then again some chips fail.... but not often.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the page there is referring to the maximum capacity of the memory controller on the motherboard. Thus, you will not be able to utilize any more than 4GB of memory.

Should you however add more than 4GB of memory, your device will not be harmed, although you might not be able to use any of the memory.